# How can you create a View in Drupal using a Rule's action?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I would like to create a module that generates a view with predefined settings when a term is created in a particular taxonomy.

I understand that a module can create a view using [hook_views_default_views()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_default_views/7), but this doesn't allow you to create a view 'on-action', as would be desirable using Rules.

As far as I can see there is no default Rule action that allows creating of views, so is it possible to programmatically create a rule with an action that can create a view?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! However, there's a dedicated StackExchange platform just for Drupal: [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com).

Comment: To maybe already answering your question, though, why do you need to create a view upon tag creation? You can add placeholders into a view and create a single view for all (existing and future) tags in a taxonomy. A general version of such a view is already existing by default.

Comment: Cheers Paul. I had a look at the default Taxonomy Term view, but this seems to have a few limitations for what I'm after. For example, I want to create a menu entry for each page (each page corresponding to a taxonomy term), and I don't see how I can do that with only a single page. So perhaps a better way to word my initial question would be to ask if it is possible to automate page creation within a view on addition of a taxonomy term.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [Taxonomy Menu Module](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu). It automatically creates menu items based on a vocabulary and integrates nicely with Views as well as Pathauto (for nice urls).

There are two Youtube Videos ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAWyw0GU49E) & [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCwD-qVS2a0)) which might help you get along the way.

The Taxonomy Menu Module will create the menu items (linking by default to `taxonomy/term/[tid]`). The default Taxonomy Term View already listens to these requests and with Pathauto you can create custom aliases (e.g. `category/[term_name]` for these links which will in turn be used for the rendering of menu items and still work with Views as internally the default urls are used.